# Building Haxe on Linux (Fedora 25)

Tags: linux, haxe, openfl, fedora-25, neko

I am trying to build the latest haxe from the GitHub source. At first I was getting this error.

```
/bin/sh: nekotools: command not found

Makefile:108: recipe for target 'haxelib' failed

make: *** [haxelib] Error 127
```

I installed nekovm from the repos and when I ran `make` again I got a new error

```
Exception : Neko_error(load.c(357) : Primitive not found : std@elf_update_section_header_for_bytecode(3))

Makefile:108: recipe for target 'haxelib' failed

make: *** [haxelib] Error 255
```

Any idea how to fix this?

**Note:** When I use the haxe package from the repos (its v3.2.1) or when I use the haxe that ships with the openfl download I have no problems. However, the precompiled binaries from haxe do not work (but that's a whole other issue).

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my `/usr/lib/neko` directory and this seems to have solved the issue. No other problems have occurred yet.